# Dll incompatibilites in c#

Tags: c#, dll

I have a C# class library which contains a number of dlls in the assembly which I have updated. The classes are executed from a .exe file. Recompiling the calling the exe is fairly tricky (not done by me). I now get the following.

> Could not load file or assembly 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, Version=0.3.1768.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Does this mean that the references used when compiling the .exe are now different from the newer dlls I have used in the assembly that the classes inherit? Note that I have kept the original dlls used to build the .exe file. So I'm curious as to the message and I'm assuming that it is because the dlls pulled in a references in the references are newer than those in the directories used for the executable.

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: I think this problem occurs because in one of your dll, another dll is included however the included dll is missing. 

For example :

in aa.dll you add referance of bb.dll. And aa.dll is need bb.dll to compile but this dll is missing.

Comment: Question is. Should I update the dlls for the executable to match those of the dlls in the classes. Or can I get away with keeping the dlls in the .exe directory? I'm in dll hell here.

Comment: I've tried fusion log viewer but I've found that it doesn't seem to pick up any output.